# Avoid Tumbleweed badge

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to delete a question with low views and no answers and also no comments for some time and re-post it in order to get more visibility and maybe an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that editing it will bring it back to the front page. You might want to consider re-writing the title too, if it got few views that means it wasn't very interesting. Of course, if it's too specialized (like a VMS question), there might just not be that much of an audience for it.

/Edit -
In that case, I would do some reading here on tags that are related to your old question, taking care to look at how the ones with good responses are written, and re-write it as a new question. No need to delete the old one : it's not like earning Tumbleweed loses you any rep points.

Comment: if the question is really old, then it won't be brought up on the front page.

Comment: provided new answer based on comments.

Comment: I just used tumbleweed badge as a way to shorten the title. Thanks for the tip on reading good questions, I'll be sure to check them out.

Answer (score 5):

It's better to edit the question with additional research and any necessary clarifications, so others might more easily be able to answer.

You have to want an answer more than anyone else. In my experience, your efforts to answer *your own* question will inspire others to assist you.

https://serverfault.com/faq#bounty

Comment: its generally just me answering my own questions, and bounty is not cheap. I know in serverfault there are almost no questions with bounty on them so it will get attention quick, but I don't find winning rep as easy as it sounds.